# node js managing device through serialport

Tags: node.js, serial-port, hex, device, node-serialport

I need a help...I'm trying to connect the device to the node js and I use serialport npm library.

```
var comport = 'COMx';
var serialPort = require("serialport");
var usb = new SerialPort(comport, {
  baudrate: 9600,
  databits: 8
});
usb.on('open',function(){
    console.log('COMx port open');
    usb.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('data received: '+data.toString());
    });
    usb.write('\5TEST\5', function(err, results) {
//05 54 45 53 54 05 command for device with 05 prefix and suffix control number
                if (results) {
                    console.log('Response received after sending message : ' + results);
                } 
        console.log('err ' + err);
        console.log('results ' + results);
    });
});
```

When I use the com port monitor and observe the transfer of data through desktop applications, it captures the data sent to the com port "05 54 45 53 54" and receives feedback.
However, when I pass it this data via nodejs Monitoring Software does not receive any response and displays an identical record content that is sent to the com port...Why?
I sent '\5TEST\5' because command need control bytes 05 on start and end of command, and "\" keep them in that format without converting in hex...
Monitoring screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mBL6.png